# MySQL Access denied for user 'root' while using LAMP

Tags: installation, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm just want to install lamp server + phpmyadmin normally
in case of when setting up **mysql** i get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I don't know what this is.
I don't know how to run php code in ubuntu because it's my first deal with linux.

Comment: What command did you use? How are you installing? What do you want to achieve? You need to give us much more information for us to help you.

Comment: i'm just try more than one command and all of it didn't work

Comment: and my achieve is wright & running php code with frameworks & cms

Comment: @amratef Take the help of pastebin.com and give us complete log .

Comment: so i want to clean all of command and start again

Comment: i'm just want the steps to remove the wrong commands and start again in a right way with right commands

Comment: If you don't give us the commands you used we can't remove them. Just edit your question and add them.

Comment: that is the frist one and i try to remove it http://www.andyhawthorne.co.uk/setting-up-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: and this the second one http://www.unixmen.com/install-lamp-with-1-command-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat/

Comment: and this is the last one http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Comment: all this links contant different commands  can you help me

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me:

Just append "***sudo***" to the beginning of that mysql command:

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

Please note the "sudo" at the beginning of that command

Comment: You don't need `sudo`, because you just connecting to a server (MySQL in this case) from some host (localhost in this case), and making an authentication via user (MySQL's root in this case) and its password. More important thing here is the `-p` argument.

Comment: Believe me, I just tried that on my linuxMint and it worked; I'm trying to install libreNMS and following instructions here: http://docs.librenms.org/Installation/Installation-Ubuntu-1604-Apache/

Comment: This worked for me, too. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set a password for `mysql`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.x
   ```
2. Now open the terminal and type:

   ```
   mysql -uroot -p
   ```

Give password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It is important to remember that the password must be after `-p`, without any space.

Comment: @felipe.zkn it is better to press enter after -p , so that password won't be displayed in the screen

Comment: Thanks for the warning! As I am on a secure place, I always use the direct form.

Comment: If the username and the password (when you enter it through command line) consists of special characters, you can enclose them in single quote marks: `mysql -u'ex@mp!e' -p'p@$$wd'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important to note on this older post that MySQL has changed some things in the past 5 years. Digital Ocean states the following in their tutorial called [How To Install MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04):

> In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), the root MySQL user is set to authenticate using the `auth_socket` plugin by default rather than with a password.

Therefore, run the following to install properly and securely:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I personally answered `y` for every prompt from the `mysql_secure_installation` and created a strong password (option `2`, if you set up the VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin). However, the particular choices here are your's to make. Either way, you will set a password under one of these prompts. Although, as you will see, you won't necessarily need the password.

After the prompts for `mysql_secure_installation` are complete. All you have to do is type the following to log in:

```
sudo mysql
```

This is because the native authentication method for MySQL 5.7 and later is `auth_socket` instead of `mysql_native_password` for better security. No need for a password, because you can only log in from the machine it's installed on.

If you need to use a password to log in from another source, or want to know more, I recommend reading [How To Install MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) in its entirety.