# MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: 12.04, server, password, mysql

In my server, everytime I try to access MySQL I get the error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

when I try `mysqladmin -u root -p password` I get

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How can I access MySQL in my Ubuntu server 12.04?

Comment: Try to avoid typing your password as a parameter on the command line, other users can find it via process listings. Much better to type it direct into the program or use a key

Comment: The syntax `-p password` is wrong, it has to be `-ppassword` but is not recommended. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131931/connecting-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Comment: Check this page for possible causes of this error and workarounds to fix this error. http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/04/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-user-host-using-password-YES.html. It may help you.

Answer (score 18):

If you're running n localhost, just type the command below in terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If you're using an external server, enter the host IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) as well:

```
mysql -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uroot -p
```

You will be prompted for your password, enter it and you will be able to access your MySQL prompt.

You can also look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/254654/163331) on how to reset your MySQL password.

Comment: i got in but i still don't know how to change or chose a password

Comment: In the answer I linked to, you have to replace the `5.x` at the end with the version of the MySQL server you're using. I'm using 5.5 so my command will be `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: so, the problem is that OP sees `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. You suggest calling `mysql -u root -p`. The result of this command is: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

Comment: `sudo mysql -u root -p` works for me, but `mysql -u root -p` does not

Comment: "...and you will be able to access your MySQL prompt." No, we're not!

Answer (score 7):

I get the same symptoms when I update, but for me the fix (after killing mysql and restarting with --skip-grant-tables to get in) is to execute

```
update mysql.user set plugin = '';
```

The update process likes to set this column to "unix_socket". I don't know what that is supposed to accomplish, but for me it breaks everything.

Comment: This solve my problem on Ubuntu 16 LTS, after trying everything.. permissions, group user. Thanx.

Comment: yes, I had run hardening script and it changed the plugin to `mysql_socket` so whatever I was set to using `PASSWORD('xxxxxx')`, was not working.

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem with this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Be extremely responsible. With this solution, you are removing MySql server and all of its data.**

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: !! Be extremely responsible. With this solution you are removing MySql server and all of it's data.

Answer (score 5):

The same as Ulrich Metzger, after upgrading my machine to Ubuntu 16.04 and Mysql-server-5.7, I couldn't log in with root because the `plugin` column changed.

My problem was not solved with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7` + removing + purging + cleaning.

I had to stop the mysql service:

`# sudo service mysql stop`

Then restart the mysql daemon with the `--no-grant-tables` option:

`# sudo mysqld_safe --no-grant-tables &`

Then in another terminal, enter the mysql console (which now doesn't need authentication) with the command `mysql`, and update the password and plugin columns via a SQL UPDATE:

```
UPDATE mysql.user 
  SET authentication_string=PASSWORD(''), 
      plugin='mysql_native_password'
WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

Finally, kill the `mysqld_safe` command, restart mysql service and connect to mysql normally:

```
# sudo service mysql start
# mysql
```

Comment: This was the only solution which worked for me! However, there's a typo, I had to use `--skip-grant-tables` instead of `--no-grant-tables`

Answer (score 4):

Set a password for mysql

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.x
```

Now open the terminal and type

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

give password and press enter

Answer (score 4):

After completely reinstalling mysql (thinking that I was using the incorrect password) I ended up with the same problem, but eventually found [Ivan Black's comment above](https://askubuntu.com/a/428253/366935) which did the trick:

`sudo mysql -u root -p`

Why I should need elevated privileges to log in with the root user is beyond me.

Comment: My guess is because the user without elevation doesn't have access to the MySQL socket, but the root user does. Connecting directly to the socket means you don't need to enter a password.

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading from ubuntu 14.4LTS to 16.4LTS the mysql root user could no more login due a wrong entry in the mysql user table's plugin column.
The upgrade sets the plugin value for the root@localhost user to **auth_socket** but the correct entry must be **mysql_native_password**, if you used mysql native password encryption before.

Comment: This is the one that's worked for me, and seems to be the root of the problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling won't do anything to fix the "problem".