# Cant connect to mysql database. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2, mysql

I installed mysql-server `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` and then did a secure installation `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and set the password to `12345`. But I cant connect to it..

```
felix@felix:/var/www/html/test$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since sön 2017-02-19 22:19:38 CET; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 18502 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─18502 /usr/sbin/mysqld

feb 19 22:19:37 felix systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
feb 19 22:19:38 felix systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.

felix@felix:/var/www/html/test$ mysqladmin -p -u root version
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''

felix@felix:/var/www/html/test$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

What is causing this? All my googling has led to people who dont know their passwords.

Comment: Lets try this: find mysql pid: `ps aux | grep mysql`, then `sudo kill mysqld.pid`, create a file" `/home/username/mysql-init` --> add this to this file: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` Then start mysql: `mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &`. Delete `delete /home/me/mysql-init` on successful start

Comment: Tried all of those. I cant connect and I cant --skip-grant-tables

Comment: Did you confirm `mysqld` was stopped? Please state in your OP what you have tried so we won't waste our time...

Comment: felix@felix:~$ service mysqld stop
Failed to stop mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not loaded.

Comment: Please run the above steps again, this time use `sudo systemctl stop mysql`...

Comment: Alright. It is stopped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54122/discussion-between-george-and-felix-rosen).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428243/mysql-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: which version of ubuntu you are using